# How to retrieve GPS coordinate in BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: android, gps, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a method in my BroadcastReceiver class which check for a sms trigger and executes functions based on the trigger fired. This is a method to filter the sms content and return the msg to send in the response sms.

I currently have a condition which on "locator" condition will register locationListener to Network/GPS. But I keep having return my "msg" with a blank content before a correct data seek of the coordinates.

I did try a while loop but I made it jumpy, I suspect a infinite loop.
Also tried a startActivityResult but unable to.

Please advice.

```
public String methodTrigger(Context context, String operation){
        String returnMsg="";

        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Lock")){
            Intent lock = new Intent(context, lockscreen.class);
            lock.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(lock);
            returnMsg = "Lock Operation Enabled";
        }else if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Locate")){
            String msg = "";
            Log.i("monitor", "Create");
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
                    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
                    test = "Latitude: "+String.valueOf(lat)+"\nLongitude: "+String.valueOf(lng);
                    Log.i("monitor", "Reading coordintes");
                }

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            };

            // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
            if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                Log.i("monitor", "Listen Network");
            }else{
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                Log.i("monitor", "Listen GPS");
            }
            Log.i("monitor", "Finish");
            returnMsg = test;
        }else if(...other functions.....
        }
        return returnMsg;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it this way, because `methodTrigger` returns before `onLocationChanged` is called.